# Generate dynamic forms that change based on form input in jSF

Tags: forms, jsf, primefaces, richfaces

I need to create a form that takes some data from the server and generate a form based on the type of the data.  For example, if I have a String, I need the form to have an input box.  If I have a List, I need the corresponding form field to have a group of checkboxes.  Is there anyway to create this type of auto-generating form?
I have been playing with data tables, and I can figure out how to generate a table that dynamically changes.  But I can't find a way to generate a form that dynamically changes.  I can probably figure out a way to create this in javascript/jquery, but is there a way using JSF/PrimeFaces/RichFaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature might interest you, it's a primefaces extension that handles creation of dynamic forms (on runtime). The form receives fields (or controls) by wish from a bean and adds them.

It's called [DynaForm](http://fractalsoft.net/primeext-showcase-mojarra/views/dynaForm.jsf;jsessionid=s9o1kru7q9zm1bir7wg2rbyyj) ; hope that helps your cause.

Comment: Thanks! This is very similar to what I was looking for.  (Though you guys did bring up a good point about handling this with Javascript instead).

Comment: jQuery will be ideal to this sort of things, along with ajax and JSON (to hit the DB from the dynamic forms).

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the `rendered` attribute, doing something like this:

```
<h:inputText rendered="#{bean.doIHaveAString}" />

<h:selectManyCheckbox rendered="#{bean.doIHaveAList}" />
```

those elements will only appear if the condition is met

Comment: I guess my problem is that there are no fixed inputs.  So someone might request a form with 4 Strings, and someone else might request a form with 4 Lists.  So for the form with 4 Strings, I would need 4 inputText arguments, and for the form with 4 Lists, I would need 4 selectManyCheckboxes. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @user2471366 this kind of pages are better handled using JavaScript, not a server side technology (like JSF).

Comment: Indeed, JavaScript or JSP seem to be better disposed for this kind of use cases.

Comment: Yes, good point. I was just wondering whether JSF could handle it. Thanks.